# Adding a promise to browser.driver.wait not working in protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I am using [node-resemble](https://github.com/kpdecker/node-resemble) image comparison library to compare two images in a protractor test. Node-resemble returns a promise which resolves with comparison data. I want protractor to wait till the results are available.

I have tried using [browser.driver.wait](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) to achieve this, but somehow it is not working. Here's the code I am using for returning a promise to browser.driver.wait:

```
var compareImage = function(path1, path2) {
    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
    var img1 = fs.readFileSync(path1);
    var img3 = fs.readFileSync(path2);
    resemble(img1).compareTo(img3).onComplete(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        deferred.fulfill(data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

And this is how I am using it:

```
var prom = compareImage(path1, path2);
browser.driver.wait(prom, 3000).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    expect(data.misMatchPercentage).toBe('0.00');
});
```

I have read the documentation and have tried to do it the way it is described, but somehow it is not working. None of the two `console.log` are logging the data to console. Here is what the documentation says:

> *Example:* Suppose you have a function, `startTestServer`, that returns a promise for when a server is ready for requests. You can
>   block a `WebDriver` client on this promise with: var started =
>   startTestServer(); driver.wait(started, 5 * 1000, 'Server should start
>   within 5 seconds'); driver.get(getServerUrl());

It seems like there is something I am missing out. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have used browser.driver.wait.

Instead use browser.wait and see how it works